# Wordpress + Nginx 404 on wp-login.php

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have this wordpress isntalled on a sobfolder `/blog/` and when accessing /wp-login.php or any other system uri, it returns 404.

The block that handle the wordpress configuration is:

```
  location ^~ /blog {
    root /home/deploy/apps;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # following works for wordpress
    # you might need to tweak it for your php-app
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~* .php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;

      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_index index.php;

      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
```

I'm not an expert on nginx configuration so, any hint as much obvious it seems is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you're *`try`*-ing something at `/blog/blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args` when you might not mean to.

By having this config already apply to requests that start with `/blog`, and then including `/blog/index.php` in the `try_files` block, you're bound to get 404s, since that won't reflect your file structure.

Put the `root` directive in the server block, and append `blog` to it, if wordpress is in that part of the filesystem and you *don't* want it in the url.

```
# (within a greater `server { ... }` block)

root /home/deploy/apps/blog;

location / {
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~* .php$ {      
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_index index.php;

  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

(Pulled from https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/)

If you do, though, remove it from the `root` directive, and configure your WP permalinks as mentioned in this SO post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253538/change-default-url-path-blog-of-blog-posts

(Also, don't forget to reload nginx after you make changes to a conf file!)